# Instantaneous displacement of a traveling sine wave with an undisturbed starting condition

Tags: waves

The equation for the instantaneous displacement of a traveling wave at time $t$, and at any position $x$ along the wave is:

$$y(x,t) = A_{max}\sin(kx +\omega t + \phi)$$

[image]

But this is only valid when the traveling wave has already formed (i.e in steady state). If the wave at time $t=0$ has displacement $0$ at every position $x$, what will the equation be then?

[image]

And what is the equation when there is a full or partial reflection?

For a standing wave in steady state the equation is:

$$y(x,t)=2A_{max}\cos(\omega t)\sin(kx)$$

But what is the equation that also describes the transient period, as shown in the picture below?

[image]

Comment: Look for the Heaviside function, also called the step function.

Comment: I'm familiar with the step function, wouldn't this would just have the wave equal 0 at all points for a certain amount of time, and then the equation will just become the same equation I gave at the start of this question? This is different from the wave shown in the second picture.

Comment: If the step function is $\theta(x-x_0-ct)$ then the step moves forward in time with the same speed $c$ as the wave.  For the reflection case there would be a second step function $\theta(x-x_0'+ct)$ to "turn on" the reflected wave.